# Regex: Match strings between two keywords mixed with useless data across multiple lines

Tags: regex

I'm trying to use NP++ regex to parse data from a file with input:

```
badstring ---
useless data
keyword1 ---
usless data
string 1 ---
random number of useless lines of characters across newlines
string 2 ---
more useless stuff
keyword2 ---
useless data
dumb badstring keyword2 ---
```

output:

```
string 1, string 2
```

For example sake, string1, string 2 and badstrings all have the same format, that's why I exclusively want to find string1 and string2 ONLY between keyword1 and keyword2.

The closest I was able to get is:

```
keyword1\r\n((.|\r\n)+?)\r\n(.+) ---\r\n((.|\r\n)+?)\r\n(.+) ---\r\n((.|\r\n)+?)keyword2
```

the problem is that I dont know the number of strings I need to capture, so I need to recursively search from the largest number of possible strings, and because I am using ((.|\r\n)+?) to match anything it always matches beyond the keyword, so when I run `keyword1 ---((.|\r\n)+?)(.+) ---((.|\r\n)+?)(.+) ---((.|\r\n)+?)(.+) ---((.|\r\n)+?)keyword2 ---` to find 3 strings it selects beyond keyword2 because the next section also contains keyword2 instead of returning no matches. Similarly if I do it searching for too many strings it will loop around and select the entire file. Any ideas?

Comment: I feel like a rudimentary parser would be more appropriate for handling this.  I do understand that this may not be possible if you are limited to using NPP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using [`(*SKIP)(*F)`](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html#pcrevariation) to skip anything from start to `keyword1` and everything from `keyword2` until end of string. The question doesn't sound like recursion would be needed.

```
(?s:\A.*?^keyword1|^keyword2.*)(*SKIP)(*F)|^.*?(?=\h---)
```

[See this demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/MM8MFW/3)

- `(?s:` opens a [non capturing group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-in-regular-expressions) with [doatall flag](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-modifiers.html#dotall) for make the dot match newlines too
- [`\A`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html#az) matches start of the string, [`^`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) matches start of line
- [`\h`](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html#whitespace) matches a horizontal space
- `.*?` matches [lazily](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#lazy) [any amount](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/quantifiers-in-regular-expressions) of [any characters](https://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html)
- `(?=` opens a [lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) for just checking condition and not consuming

Comment: @Toto thanks :) well not sure yet if that's what OP after

Comment: Thank you so much for the eagerness to help, but NP++ and Atom both don't think that is a valid expression. I tried playing around with it, but couldn't figure out the problem 

Here is the input I am trying to process https://pastebin.com/VKSw5D0Q I am specifically trying to capture every (network adapter) --+ between NETWORK --+ and PORTS --+ Because I dont know how many network adapters there will be, I need to search for say 4 first, then 3, then 2, then 1, but only the correct number of network adapter should match then replace.

Comment: @fatguy1121 Seems to work as desired, see [this regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/MM8MFW/4). Getting two matches. I tested this of course in NP++ where I got the same results like in demo. I'm using NP++ 7.7.1. Also be sure to check the regex checkbox in search/replace and uncheck the `.` *matches newline* checkbox and also uncheck the *extended* checkbox.

Comment: YAY! This is so much better than my previous method, skips about 30 steps in one regex. Thank You!

Comment: So, could I take the matches to a capture group and replace them onto a new line like NETADAPTERS:\1, \2, \3 (and so on until all matches are replaced)
I'm almost certain that regex doesn't offer a way to capture to groups recursively without numbering each group directly right?

Comment: @fatguy1121 You can replace eg with `$0` the full match, so if you want to prepend `NETADAPTERS` at each match you'd [replace with `NETADAPTERS: $0`](https://regex101.com/r/MM8MFW/5). Just open a new question for new problem as it's difficult to describe it in a short comment :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something, but can't you just use the straight-forward

```
keyword1[\s\S]*(string1)[\s\S]*(string2)[\s\S]*keyword2
```

This should do what you describe.